# Move ctor dilemma

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In order to disable copying of my class I'm suppose to declare as private but not define `operator=(const MyClass&)` and `MyClass(const MyClass&)` - do I have to also disable move ctor for this class?

Answer (score 5):

It is still up to discussion whether move constructors will be implicitly generated (and when).

See [this PDF](http://www2.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3174.pdf) by Stroustrup from 2010-10-17 with the subtitle **Should move operations be generated by default?**

BTW, in C++0x you can `= delete` functions rather than make them priviate and undefined.

```
class non_copyable {
    public:
    non_copyable(const non_copyable&) = delete;
    non_copyable& operator=(const non_copyable&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly I work on VS2010 and they still didn't implemented delete construct. Good to know anyway.

Comment: @There that's OK, they haven't implemented default generation of move constructors either so you don't have to explicitly disable them.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [VS 2010 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd293668.aspx):

> Unlike the default copy constructor,
>   the compiler does not provide a
>   default move constructor.

So for VS 2010, it's not necessary to hide that. They don't specifically discuss default move assignment operators, but I assume they won't generate one, either.